# Error when updating username via a signal

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm wondering how I can update a Django Users username.  I am using the default auth model, with a `OneToOne` relationship for a custom `Profile`.  The `Profile` can be updated via the end user, and a signal has been set to listen to the change and update accordingly.

Even if the username is gibberish or isn't changed at all the same error occurs, so I'm not sure why the unique constraint is being violated.

```
# models

class Profile(models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name='profile')


# signals

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile, weak=False)
def sync_profile_auth(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.pk:
        instance.client.first_name = instance.first_name
        instance.client.last_name = instance.last_name
        instance.client.email = instance.email
        instance.client.username = instance.email
        instance.client.save()

# error
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(myuser@admin.com) already exists.
```

Cheers.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the code you shared with us! You somehow try to add a user with existing username or update.

Comment: @Jamie what do you expect when someone try to change the username, to an existing username?

Comment: @PauloPessoa - I want the username to update in sync with the email, unless the email address has already been taken

Comment: @ozgur - You were correct, can you change your comment to an answer reply so I can update and close please.

Comment: @JamieStrauss i think you have a big problem with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:**

Maybe you are trying to update a user ,  already exists in database.

**Second problem:**

```
username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
    help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and '
                '@/./+/-/_ characters'),
    validators=[
        validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'), _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
    ])
```

The variable username, has `max_length=30`. if the user has a email with more than 30 characters, he can't register.

This can be **helpful for you.**
[Customize User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: Hi Paolo,  I have a set of custom migrations that modify the database tables to allow for longer usernames.

Comment: returning to the problem, what happening if you try to update a object without change the username? u got a key error again, alright?